# Wordpress query with multiple meta meta keys

Tags: wordpress

Can someone tell me what wrong with this query.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['lokacija'] ) && !empty( $_GET['lokacija'] ) ) {
        $lokacija = $_GET['lokacija'];
    } else { $lokacija = ''; }
    if ( isset( $_GET['tip'] ) && !empty( $_GET['tip'] ) ) {
        $tip = $_GET['tip'];
    } else { $tip = ''; }
    if ( isset( $_GET['sobe'] ) && !empty( $_GET['sobe'] ) ) {
        $sobe = $_GET['sobe'];
    } else { $sobe = ''; }

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      $args2 = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'nekretnine',
        'paged' => $paged,
            if ($lokacija != '') {
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array (
                        'key' => 'lokacija',
                        'value' => $lokacija.''
                        ),
                )
            } 

        );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
```

This code gives me error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ')' in
>   ***/wp-content/themes/gs/page-nek-pretraga.php on line 23;

Line 23 is line that starts with if (`$lokacija`)...

What i want to do is to use multiple meta_query that i can get from php get (`www.blabla./com/page1/?lokacija=foo&tip=foo&sobe=3`)

But, i want it only if lets say `$lokacija` is not empty. Same for other two (possible 5-6 later) fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include `if` condition in array. Whatever you are trying to achieve with above code is you can achieve with this following code.

```
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'nekretnine',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

if ($lokacija != '') {
    $args2['meta_query'] = array(
        array (
                'key' => 'lokacija',
                'value' => $lokacija.''
            ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for multiple custom fields we have to join the meta table twice.
So the copy of the table is joined with a different temporary table name.

```
    global $wpdb; $query = " SELECT * FROM {$wpdb--->prefix}posts
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m1
  ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = m1.post_id )
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m2
  ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = m2.post_id )
WHERE
{$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post'
AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND ( m1.meta_key = 'date' AND m1.meta_value > '2010-12-05 00:00:00' )
AND ( m1.meta_key = 'date' AND m1.meta_value < '2010-12-12 00:00:00' ) AND ( m2.meta_key = 'some_other_meta_value' AND m2.meta_value != '' ) GROUP BY {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date
DESC;
```

For More Details Visit : http://realtuts.com/write-custom-wordpress-sql-query-multiple-meta-values/

";